# Conditional rendering if slots are not passed from the parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Take the code below as an example:

```
<header>
  <slot name='header'></slot>
  <template v-if='?'>
    <h1>{{ someInput }}</h1>
  </template>
</header>
```

I want to show the `<h1>{{ some input }}</h1>` if nothing gets passed through the slots. What could I use as the condition in `v-if` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough:

```
<header>
  <slot name='header'>
    <h1>{{ someInput }}</h1>
  </slot>
</header>
```

> Anything originally inside the  tags is considered fallback
> content. Fallback content is compiled in the child scope and will only
> be displayed if the hosting element is empty and has no content to be
> inserted.

From [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot).

Comment: That was easy, I found a way to check using `$slots.<name>` but your way gets rid of that overhead.

Comment: Yep, an easy one.